# How can I physically prepare for high altitude hiking?

Tags: hiking

I intend to go to Tibet in August. I play badminton,tabletennis or volleyball every week and my fitness is decent. But I have not been exposed to high altitudes like in Tibet (16000 ft; 4900 m). How can I keep myself ready for a trek in Tibet in the coming 4 months?

Comment: What do you play every week? I found this link that somebody could use to put together an answer: http://www.wikihow.com/Prepare-for-a-High-Altitude-Hike

Comment: +1, as someone who lives near the rockies, my experience has been people's reactions are personal and unpredictable, without much correlation to overall "fitness" level.

Comment: Being fit is not a waranty of not being altitude sick. It has to do the way you will manage the lack of oxygen.